# Why are my two node.js servers mutually exclusive?

Tags: node.js, supervisord, upstart

On my ubuntu server I have two node.js servers which serve different purposes. They are accessed on different ports and work fine apart from each other. Problem is, if one of them is running, the other one is not started by upstart. Whichever application comes first starts fine using `sudo start app1`, but for the second app (`sudo start app2`) I get a successful response, but the process isn't there and trying to stop it with upstart yields `stop:Unknown job: app2`

Both use upstart and supervisord to start on boot and stay running. The config files for one of the applications (Countly) [can be found here](https://github.com/Countly/countly-server/tree/master/bin/config). The configuration files for the other application are very similar (I copied and modified countly's).

I'm way over my head with supervisord and upstart here, so I suspect this is where the problem is. Additionally, if I start countly using upstart I can manually start my other server (by doing something like `node myServer.js`) without trouble.

Can supervisord be used for two applications like this?

I have trouble making sense of the logs, but I don't see anything which looks related.

I'm completely out of ideas. Please advise.

---

### edit: conf files

The contents of /etc/init/myApp-supervisor.conf:

```
description "myApplication"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec /usr/bin/supervisord --nodaemon --configuration /home/username/my-app-dir/config/supervisord.conf
```

and /home/username/my-app-dir/config/supervisord.conf:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=warn
pidfile=/var/log/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
minfds=1024
minprocs=200
user=root
childlogdir=/var/log/

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factor = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[group:my-app]
programs=my-app-incoming-data, my-app-file-server

[program:my-app-incoming-data]
command=node /home/username/my-app-dir/data-accepter.js
directory=.
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/username/my-app-dir/log/data-accepter.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=500MB
stdout_logfile_backups=50
std_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
loglevel=warn

[program:my-app-file-server]
command=http-server -p 8877 /home/username/my-app-dir/files
directory=.
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/username/my-app-dir/log/file-server.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=500MB
stdout_logfile_backups=50
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB
stdout_events_enabled=false
loglevel=warn
```

---

### edit2: log files

/var/log/supervisord.log - (I have several repeated errors here but from way back in january so I guess they are not relevant)

```
2013-01-30 15:01:20,288 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2013-01-30 15:01:22,399 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2013-01-30 15:01:22,399 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
```

/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log - (again, many duplicate entries from long ago probably unrelated to this issue)

```
2013-01-29 21:12:46,140 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2013-01-29 21:13:32,975 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2013-01-29 21:13:33,075 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2013-01-29 21:13:33,075 WARN cElementTree not installed, using slower XML parser for XML-RPC
2013-01-29 21:13:33,075 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2013-01-29 21:13:33,082 INFO daemonizing the supervisord process
2013-01-29 21:13:33,084 INFO supervisord started with pid 743
2013-01-29 21:24:43,500 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2013-01-30 03:04:47,566 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2013-01-30 03:04:47,747 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
```

Answer (score 1):

Countly appends below block to the upstart config after running the installation script ([here](https://github.com/Countly/countly-server/blob/master/bin/countly.install.sh#L74)).

```
exec /usr/bin/supervisord --nodaemon --configuration $DIR/config/supervisord.conf
```

I think you are missing this part from your own upstart config.

Comment: that's right! I saw this in the setup script, but maybe I forgot all about it when I was setting up my own. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Oh, I didn't forget it after all. I've got this in there but modified a bit: ```exec /usr/bin/supervisord --nodaemon --configuration /home/username/myAppDir/config/supervisord.conf```

Comment: I've added the contents of my config files to the question. Thanks for your help and your work on Countly (it's great). I'll be reading up on supervisord today to see if I am doing something wrong there.

Comment: Is there anything in /var/log/supervisord.log after executing `sudo start myApplication`?

Comment: nothing gets added, no. I have some errors from a long time ago, but that is it. I've added the last few entries in my log files to the question if you want to take a look. I am sure it is just some silly mistake since I am not familiar with these tools.